# Non-separable Hilbert spaces in duals

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

A topological space $X$ satisfies the *countable chain condition* if every family of pairwise disjoint open sets in $X$ is countable. I am looking for a reference to the following fact:

Suppose that $X$ is a compact, non-metrizable space satisfying the countable chain condition. Then the dual space of $C(X)$ contains a non-separable Hilbert space.

Any hints where to find this theorem appreciated.

EDIT: This is not true. There exist separable scattered compact spaces $X$, in which case $C(X)^* = \ell_1(|X|)$.

Comment: Do you mean every family of pairwise disjoint **open** sets? Without any assumption on the sets, this is equivalent to $X$ being countable!

Comment: @spooky you should post this as answer. Btw (+1) for simple example.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an uncountable family of infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ which have finite intersection. Consider the Boolean subalgebra of the power-set algebra $\wp(\mathbb{N})$ generated by $\mathcal{A}$  and all finite subsets. The Stone space $K$ of this algebra is scattered (actually of Cantor-Bandixon height 3), which is separable as $\mathbb{N}$ is dense in $K$. Since $K$ is scattered, $C(K)^* \cong \ell_1(|K|)$. Consequently, $C(K)^*$ contains no reflexive infinite-dimensional subspace.

The spaces $K$ of the above form have googlable names: *Mrówka space*, *Mrówka-Isbell space*.

Comment: (+1) one more time